# How to resolve the transitive dependencies of different versions?

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose my application depends on two libraries one of which is Spark.

Spark has the transitive dependency of `com.fasterxml.jackson`(specific version and not configurable).

Another depending library also has the same transitive dependency, but a newer version(will not work with the version Spark requires).

So basically both versions are required when testing(unit tests) the app.

What would be a recommended way(workaround) to co-exist both versions? if any

Comment: What happens when you run the app? Only one is required? If you need both of them to run you might get runtime exceptions as only one will be loaded (in case the one that is not loaded functionality is actually used)

Answer (score 0):

You can try shading the problematic dependency with jarjar-abrams. Shading is a process where the bytecode of the library is rewritten to move its classes to a different package, and all references to these classes are rewritten as well to match.

https://eed3si9n.com/jarjar-abrams

Unfortunately it often doesn't work when reflection is involved – I don't know if Jackson uses reflection in a way that's incompatible with this process, but it's worth a shot.